# iOS 11 navigation bar bottom line

Tags: ios, xcode, navigationbar, iphone-x

Just started to use Xcode 9 and iOS 11 today, I found there is border line created about 3 px above the bottom of navigation bar. I never seen same thing in iOS 10. Any idea how to remove it? To make it clear it is not the iPhone X home button in the screenshot below, but the line in the navigation bar

[image: iPhone 7 Plus iOS 11 screenshot]

Comment: which one you said

Comment: I think this border has nothing to deal with navigation bar in iOS 11. I also migrated my old project to Xcode 9, but I am not getting any such border. So, this border may be due to something else or related to UI of your screen.
Have a look to these guidelines : https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/ Hope it helps you :)

Comment: I think people confused with what I mean by 'border line created about 3 px above the bottom of navigation bar', It is not the iPhone X home button I am talking about. But the line one navigation bar !! I even got one negative point for that because someone think I asked such stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: there is a bottom shadow line created by the navigation bar which can't be accessed directly, and I have to write code replace the image for that shadow. For anyone run into the same problem, this is the code:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"11.0")) {
    // Remove navigation bar bottom shadow line in iOS 11
    [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[self generateSinglePixelImageWithColor:[FillrThemeManager sharedInstance].theme.fillViewNavigationBarTintColor] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [self generateSinglePixelImageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}

- (UIImage *)generateSinglePixelImageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
  CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0f);

  CGContextRef theContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(theContext, color.CGColor);
  CGContextFillRect(theContext, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, imageSize.width, imageSize.height));

  CGImageRef theCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(theContext);
  UIImage *theImage;
  if ([[UIImage class] respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:)]) {
      theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:theCGImage scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
  } else {
      theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:theCGImage];
  }
  CGImageRelease(theCGImage);

  return theImage;
}
```